# How to order bubbles according their size and not by the order of their datasets?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bubble chart with multiple datasets. Two points of two different datasets may have the same coordinates (x and y-value) and lay on the same place in the chart. Because the display order of the points is determined according the order of the datasets, the smaller point could be completely covered by the bigger point in front of it.

Is there a option or a way, to display the points in order of their bubble size?

Simplified example of four points. The solution must also work for multiple datasets with each 30+ points.
I am searching a solution to draw the blue point in front of the red point, for the left pair and let the right pair as it is. This order must be independent of the order of the datasets, as it is per point and not per dataset.

Sorting the datasets seems to be no option for me, as the order cannot be determined per dataset, but instead must be determined for every coordinate/point. When drawing a point, it must be checked for this particular coordinate, if any other point with the same coordinates exists **and** if this point is greater than the current point (if true, the greater point must be drawn before, to not cover up the current point).

```js
const config = {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 1,
            r: 20
          },
          {
            x: 2,
            y: 1,
            r: 15
          }
        ],
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 1,
            r: 15
          },
          {
            x: 2,
            y: 1,
            r: 20
          }
        ],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        suggestedMin: 0,
        suggestedMax: 3
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      }
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSCanvas').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSCanvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-LlFvdZpYhQdASf4aZfSpmyHD6+waYVfJRwfJrBgki7/Uh+TXMLFYcKMRim65+o3lFsfk20vrK9sJDute7BUAUw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just sort the data in the datasets and then the datasets themselves before drawing them.

An easy way to do this is provided by [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

First sort the data within each dataset like this:

```
config.data.datasets.forEach(function(element){
    element.data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.r - b.r;
    });
});
```

Then you can sort the data sets by their smallest element like this:

```
config.data.datasets.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.data[0].r - b.data[0].r;
});
```

After that, you can regularly pass your config object with ordered datasets to your library call just the way you do it above:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: This would help, if one dataset has all the smallest bubbles. But if the smallest bubbles are spread across all datasets, sorting of the datasets would not help. Or do I miss a point here?
I have clarified my question.

Comment: Ah, i see. I wasn't aware `data` could have more then one element before you clarified it. I will change my answer to regard this.

Comment: This considers only the first element of each dataset, if two points in the middle of the array have the same coordinates, this would not work. I am looking for a solution where the order of the datasets does not matter, tried to further clarify my question.

Comment: Sorting in some form will have to be performed to achieve your goal. If you do it yourself or maybe the library does it for you internally. Also, you can rely on the first element when you sort all the elements inside the dataset first, what i am doing in the first section.